# Estratégia para diminuir repetição de código c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api-2

Estou precisando diminuir a quantidade de métodos na minha controller que tem praticamente o mesmo código, o que diferencia eles é o método chamado na hora do GET.

Exemplo:

**Classe**: **ConsultaController**

```
[HttpGet("GetArquivoBaixaVert")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetArquivoBaixaVert([FromQuery] int? idHeader)
    {
        var response = new ResponseConsulta<ArquivoBaixaVert>();

        try
        {
            if (idHeader == null)
            {
                response.StatusCode = "400";
                response.Descricao = "Dados Enviados nulos ou inválidos";

                return FactoryResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response);
            }

            using (var negocio = new ArquivoRecNegocio(""))
            {
                response.Data = negocio.ListarArquivoBaixaVert(idHeader.Value);
            }

            if (response.Data.Count == 0)
            {
                response.StatusCode = "404";
                response.Descricao = "Não foram encontrados arquivos com o id enviado";

                return FactoryResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, response);
            }

            response.StatusCode = "200";

            return FactoryResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response.StatusCode = "500";
            response.Descricao = $"Erro ao processar, contate o administrador, exceção: {e.Message}";

            return FactoryResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, response);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region GetArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis([FromQuery] int? idHeader)
    {
        var response = new ResponseConsulta<ArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis>();

        try
        {
            if (idHeader == null)
            {
                response.StatusCode = "400";
                response.Descricao = "Dados Enviados nulos ou inválidos";

                return FactoryResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response);
            }

            using (var negocio = new ArquivoRecNegocio(""))
            {
                response.Data = negocio.ListarArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis(idHeader.Value);
            }

            if (response.Data.Count == 0)
            {
                response.StatusCode = "404";
                response.Descricao = "Não foram encontrados arquivos com o id enviado";

                return FactoryResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, response);
            }

            response.StatusCode = "200";

            return FactoryResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response.StatusCode = "500";
            response.Descricao = $"Erro ao processar, contate o administrador, exceção: {e.Message}";

            return FactoryResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, response);
        }
    }
```

Percebe-se que o código é praticamente o mesmo, o que vai muda é a chamada **negocio.ListarArquivoBaixaVert** e **negocio.ListarArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis**.

Dentro dessa controller existem vários métodos GET com essas mesmas repetições.

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer com que isso fique em um único método? De repente algum método genérico? É possível?

Comment: As classes de controller devem ser filhas de uma superclasse, não? Você pode criar um método `protected` na superclasse, que recebe como parâmetros essas poucas diferenças, e nos controllers filhos, você simplesmente chama o método "genérico".

Answer (score -3):

A minha ideia foi pegar as duas partes diferentes do dois metodos que são

var response = new ResponseConsulta();

response.Data = negocio.ListarArquivoBaixaVert(idHeader.Value);

Usei metodos genericos para preencher os dois valores e a partir disso eu construo a mensagem http padrão passando esses dois parametros para um metodo generico que vai ler e retornar um erro de acordo com a logica implementada, como não tinha todos os valores do seu código pode ser que eu não tenha feito um código compilavel mas acredito que com pequenos ajustes possa resolver o seu problema mas acredito que a abordagem possa ser essa.

```
[HttpGet("GetArquivoBaixaVert")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetArquivoBaixaVert([FromQuery] int? idHeader)
        {
            var response = retornaResponseConsulta(new ArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis());
            response.Data = retornaListarNegocio<ArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis>(new ArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis(), idHeader);
            return RetornarErroMapeado(response, idHeader);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis([FromQuery] int? idHeader)
        {
            var response = retornaResponseConsulta(new ArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis());
            response.Data = retornaListarNegocio<ArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis>(new ArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis(), idHeader);
            return RetornarErroMapeado(response, idHeader);
        }
        // esse string tem que ser o tipo de response que como vc declarou var eu nao consegui descobrir
        public HttpResponseMessage RetornarErroMapeado(string response, int idHeader)
        {
            try
            {
                if (idHeader == null)
                {
                    response.StatusCode = "400";
                    response.Descricao = "Dados Enviados nulos ou inválidos";

                    return FactoryResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response);
                }      

                if (response.Data.Count == 0)
                {
                    response.StatusCode = "404";
                    response.Descricao = "Não foram encontrados arquivos com o id enviado";

                    return FactoryResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, response);
                }

                response.StatusCode = "200";

                return FactoryResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                response.StatusCode = "500";
                response.Descricao = $"Erro ao processar, contate o administrador, exceção: {e.Message}";

                return FactoryResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, response);
            }
        }

        private object retornaResponseConsulta<T>(T? objectResponse)
        {
            switch (objectResponse)
            {
                case ArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis:
                    return new ResponseConsulta<ArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis>(); 
                case ArquivoBaixaVert:
                    return new ResponseConsulta<ArquivoBaixaVert>();
                default: 
                    return null;
            }
        }

        public List<String> retornaListarNegocio<T>(T? objectResponse, string idHeaderValue)
        {
            List<String> retorno = new();
            switch (objectResponse)
            {
                case ArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis:
                    using (var negocio = new ArquivoRecNegocio(""))
                    {
                        retorno = negocio.ListarArquivoCnab500RemessaFromtis(idHeader.Value);
                    }
                    break;
                case ArquivoBaixaVert:
                    using (var negocio = new ArquivoRecNegocio(""))
                    {
                        retorno = negocio.ListarArquivoBaixaVert(idHeaderValue);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return null;
            }

            return retorno;
        }
```